# Apache 2.4: RegEx for Alias in httpd conf

Tags: regex, apache, httpd.conf, vhosts

Below is the Alias aI have in my apache 2.4 httpd conf file
For every release we'll update the version number and am trying to use a regex to catch the changes instead of manually changing the version number every time

For example our current version is Passport14200(14 is the year number and 2 is for second release in 2014) our next release in this year will be Passport14300( 3rd release in 2014) and our first release in 2015 will be Passport15100

This is how my httpd conf file looks like now

```
Alias /Passport14200 C:/Passport/tomcat/webapps/?Passport
<Directory C:/DC/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport>
    Require all denied
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|jpg|png|js|css|ico)$">
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
</Directory>
```

Am wondering is there a way to alias with a regex so that it catches Passport[\d{5}]?

I am new to the Regularexpressions, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you need an Alias anyway? Did you hear about `mod_rewrite`? There is `AliasMatch` directive http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch

Comment: @Cheery Am completely new to apache conf files and this is my first assignment so I have no clue of mod_rewrite and where to start on this assignment. Could you please give me an example of using  mod_rewrite / AliaMatch in my scenario, i tried looking at examples but I couldnt co-relate to my case since all the examples are with strings instead of numbers

Comment: At first you have to explain in more details - do you want alias to point to the same folder or each alias to each own folder?

Comment: Every Alias points to a same folder `C:/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every Alias points to a same folder
>   C:/DC/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport

This will match any alias starting with /Passport to the same folder.

```
AliasMatch ^/Passport.* C:/DC/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport
<Directory C:/DC/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport>
    Require all denied
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|jpg|png|js|css|ico)$">
        Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
</Directory>
```

If you want to be sure that there are only 5 digits after `Passport` - use `AliasMatch ^/Passport\d{5} C:/DC/Passport/tomcat/webapps/Passport`

Comment: After switching to AliasMatch I couldnt access resources from filesystem directory, can you please help me with my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912490/aliasmatch-with-regex-notworking-in-apache-2-4