# AliasMatch With Regex NotWorking in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, vhosts, mod-alias, apache2.4

I used to have Alias as below for /CollabPortal14300  which was working fine

```
Alias /CollabPortal14300 D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/
Alias /dc/api/entity/EmailDocument/\d+/DocumentVersion/1\.0 D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/core/html/blank.html

<Directory D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Require all denied
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|jpg|png|js|css|ico)$">
        Require all Granted
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
</Directory>
```

But we trying to eliminate the numbers from the Alias and trying to use RegEx instead. So I switched to AliasMatch as below

```
AliasMatch /CollabPortal\d{5} D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/
```

After switching  `AliasMatch /CollabPortal\d{5}` apache couldnt access the resources in `D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/`

Below are the access logs

```
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 403 246
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 403 248
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js HTTP/1.1" 403 262
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 403 251
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.treeview.js HTTP/1.1" 403 257
fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c - - [12/Nov/2014:15:10:52 -0600] "GET /CollabPortal14300/core/js/lib/jquery.treeview.async.js HTTP/1.1" 403 263
```

And in the error log I see

```
[Thu Nov 13 18:21:18.278759 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 78888:tid 928] [client fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c:58633] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/, referer: https://dc-rpalle7/CollabPortal/enduser/listscreens/show.do
```

Can someone please help me why AliasMatch is not working?

Comment: Do you have to use ipv6? Check error logs, not access logs

Comment: Your requests to server are made through ipv6, look at the address `fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c` As you can see, the AliasMatch is working. The problem is in the config of the server that prevents access to the folder. Do you have any `.htaccess` in it?

Comment: @Cheery I didnt notice that, How should I handle IPV6 in my scenario?

Comment: You can use ipv6, but there might be some other problems due to the server's config. Again, `authz_core:error` shows that the problem is with `authz_core` module. It should work fine with `FilesMatch`, but may be you have some other config not listed here. Try to remove slash at the end of the path in AliasMatch

Comment: Also.. `Directives in the configuration files are case-insensitive, but arguments to directives are often case sensitive.` Try to change to `granted`

Comment: @Cheery changed to `granted` still its not working, what other config files you want me to add here?

Comment: Did you restart apache after changes? check for `.htaccess` file in that folder or in the folders above it - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Yes I did restart my apache and I am not using `.htaccess`

Comment: `D:/Dev/Projects/CollabPortal/CollabPortal/target/CollabPortal/` remove slash at the end. I do not see other reasons in the listed config. Also, check in access log what was requested at `Thu Nov 13 18:21:18.278759 2014` by `fe80::f48e:b1a2:4f75:7c9c:58633`

Comment: removed slash at the end, that didnt work either :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64908/discussion-between-ranpaul-and-cheery).